# Ошибка с ImageView на api17

Tags: android, изображения

При запуске на api17( с маленьким экраном Galaxy S3), выбивает эту ошибку. Ошибка выбивается в тот момент,когда я открываю Activity с элементом картинки CircleImageView.На api22 всё работает отлично.
Как решить эту проблему?

Пример layout с Circle:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="by.ittech.test_chat.Profile.Profile"
    android:weightSum="1">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="155dp"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/tvPhoto"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="119dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/man"
            app:siBorderColor="@color/white"
            app:siBorderWidth="6dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:text="@string/profile_name"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            tools:gravity="end" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/e"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:text="@string/profile_email"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            tools:gravity="end" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:text="@string/profile_phone"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            tools:gravity="end" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Ошибки:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: by.ittech.test_chat, PID: 3313
                                                                   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                       at by.ittech.test_chat.Profile.Profile.onCreateView(Profile.java:54)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                       at by.ittech.test_chat.Profile.Profile.onCreateView(Profile.java:54) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020175 a=-1 r=0x7f020175}
                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3415)
                                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
                                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
                                                                       at com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.ShaderImageView.<init>(ShaderImageView.java:24)
                                                                       at com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView.<init>(CircularImageView.java:18)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                       at by.ittech.test_chat.Profile.Profile.onCreateView(Profile.java:54) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013) 
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: Это похоже на баг библиотеки, обратитесь к автору с отчетом об ошибке.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja спасибо

Comment: Только судя по гитхабу, автор забросил его.

Comment: drawable/man - это у Вас что? Не вектор случаем?